# Eve framework: can't set attribute

Tags: put, webhooks, oncreate, eve

I'm using Eve frameworks with it's hooks.
I'm also using `on_insert` hook for creating data. I've enabled `PUT` method, because it causes an error for `POST`.

Sending `PUT` requests looks like:

```
requests.put("http://127.0.0.1:7000/users", headers=headers, json={"name": "John", "age": 30})
```

It raises an error:

```
('message: ', u'{"_status": "ERR", "_error": {"message": "An exception occurred: can\'t set attribute", "code": 400}}')
```

('status: ', 400)

Comment: What' s the error for POST?

Comment: @gcw, eve.exceptions.ConfigException: Unallowed [users] item  method(s): POST. Supported: GET, PATCH, DELETE, PUT

Comment: Seems you need to add the POST method in the `resource_methods` of your resource configuration to be able to post. See http://python-eve.org/config.html#resource-item-endpoints.
Also, when using PUT, you should replace an existing item, not PUT to the resource.